# Windows batch FOR loop with two commands to create a text file

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd

I want to create a text file that has the name of the files in a directory, then the text (content) of each file:

dir fileI >> all.txt & type fileI >> all.txt are the two commands, fileI being each individual file.

Using examples I saw here, I am trying to use the following, but could not make much headway.

```
FOR /L %i in (1,1,28) do dir %i & type %i >> all.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: Double your percent signs in batch files: `%%i`

Comment: @Dúthomhas, this is only valid if you want to use the command in a [tag:batch file]…

Comment: `(for %i in (*.*) do echo(%~i& type "%~i" & echo/) > all.txt`?

Comment: Where each filename begins can be difficult to see, but this gives the content. `TYPE * >all.txt 2>&1` The `all.txt` file should be placed into a different directory. `TYPE * >"%USERPROFILE%\all.txt" 2>&1`

Comment: Thank you all. With your help, I got a solution!